# Static sidebar inside centered body?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/6wCyr/544/

I'm trying to create a fixed sidebar that doesn't scroll with the rest of the page. What I have so far works, but I also want it to be centered in the main container with the header and content divs.

You can see in the jsfiddle that if you expand the preview box, the header and content are centered but the sidebar is not, because i have set it to:

```
position:fixed;
```

setting it to

```
position:absolute;
```

puts it inside the div and centers it, but then it scrolls.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I want the sidebar to act like it does if I set the position to absolute. So if I change the size of the page, it stays right next to the content and doesn't overlap it.

Answer (score 0):

To position a fixed element within another div (.container in your case) you need to give the fixed element a right and left: 0; and a margin-left and right:auto like shown below. The position of the parent element needs to be relative, like you've done correctly. So just update the left,right,margin-left and margin-right and you're good to go!

```
.sidebar {
position:fixed;
min-height: 800px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 200px;
background:#b6ff00;
border-radius: 20px ;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8SdK2/

Comment: I don't want the sidebar centered inside the content though. Changing the right to a negative value moves it to the right spot, but then the behavior is wrong.

Comment: would this do ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iEvkb , based on my answer , using the `position:fixed;` element as a container laying over body. But , very fast, for big content, `position:fixed` might hide part of it since it won't scroll and only takes windows browser as reference to be sized ...

Comment: I got that to work, by changing the margin-left to the percent I need. But changing the size of the page changes the header and content sizes (since those are percents) but the sidebar does not change with them.

Comment: @Bobo maybe you should make something in photoshop to make clear what you mean. I surely want to help, but can't seem to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to use a container in `position:fixed;` and inside it, set your element as you ould if it was in `<body>`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hJxnf

*(extra css as background and height to test scrolling)*

```
html,body {
  background:#333;
  height:200%;
}
body, p {
  background:yellow linear-gradient(to bottom,yellow 50%,lightgray 50%);
  width:800px;
  margin:auto;
}
#fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```
<div id="fixed">
  <p> center </p>
</div>
```